# How to integrate JIRA with Robot Framework scripts of pycharm?

Tags: selenium, pycharm, robotframework, jira, jira-xray

I have my automation scripts written in Pycharm using Python-Selenium-Robot Framework. I want to integrate it with JIRA to keep the track of result and other aspects with JIRA issues.
Is there any way to achieve it? I checked for XRay plugin but not able to get the detailed tutorial for the configuration. Any suggestions? TIA.

Comment: 1. Are you using Jira cloud or Jira datacenter/onpremises? 2. What Xray configuration are you referring to? Do you already have Xray installed in your Jira instance?

Comment: JIRA onpremise, I dont have XRay already there. I was refering https://www.getxray.app/try-now?hsCtaTracking=ccffd54d-52dd-4a85-b1eb-876cdda3b8e5|c39cbdfd-dec9-493a-b6bd-876fbeb42f7e

Comment: Is it worth to provide an answer related to Xray? Unsure as you mentioned you don't have it anymore

Comment: Ya but my client is planning for it and before that I want to check tutorials and material to understand it entirely and specific with robot framework automation scripts.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Jira "on-premises" (server/datacenter), then I would advise you to have a look at [this tutorial](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Testing+using+Robot+Framework+integration+in+Python+or+Java).
There's a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/bitcoder/WebDemo) with the corresponding code.
The integration is straighforward: you just need to upload the test results from RF (e.g., output.xml) to a [specific endpoint](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Import+Execution+Results+-+REST#ImportExecutionResultsREST-RobotFrameworkXMLresults). You can do that with a HTTP POST request (with curl, for example) or from your CI/CD tool, such as Jenkins; for Jenkins, and some other tools, there is a [free plugin](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Integration+with+Jenkins).

Example of a shell script to upload the results (please adapt it accordingly)

```
#!/bin/bash

curl -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -u admin:admin -F "file=@output.xml" "http://192.168.56.102/rest/raven/2.0/import/execution/robot?projectKey=ROB&testPlanKey=ROB-12&testEnvironments=$BROWSER"
```

There's no special configuration to make in Xray. You just need to upload the test results and that will automatically provision the corresponding Test entities (as Jira issues), and report the results against them.
In RF it's possible to do some interesting stuff, like adding tags on the test cases, in case you want to link those tests to some existing Story issue (i.e., cover them), during the import process of the test results.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was reading your article https://www.getxray.app/blog/how-to-integrate-robot-framework-with-xray. I wanted to know how should I connect my pycharm script connection with JIRA/Xray to directly run it from JIRA. Currently I am running in pycharm terminal.

Comment: You may upload results from your terminal or pycharm console to Jira/Xray; if you wish to trigger the run of tests from Jira side, then that's harder to achieve. I would say that it doesn't make sense to trigger the tests to run on some editor; usually what users ask for is to trigger the tests on some CI tool, such as Jenkins or similar.  For that, you may want to give a look at https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Integration+with+Automation+for+Jira . Once again, it's not something straighforward and may require a bit finetunning.

Comment: Thanks Segio, I will check this and if any query comes then will put here.